# Import org.springframework cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a simple HelloWorld application with Spring DI. I created a Java project and imported some tutorial classes, one of which is simple this:

```
package helloworld;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class HelloWorldSpring {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // get the bean factory
        BeanFactory factory = getBeanFactory();
```

However I'm getting the following error: `The import org.springframework cannot be resolved`.
I'm using Eclipse Spring Tool Suite 3.7.2, and I thought that by using this Eclipse version when I clicked "Fix project setup", it would add these dependencies for me. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to add these dependencies manually even in STS? If yes, what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Kindly show you pom.xml

Comment: are you using any dependency management tools like maven or gradle.. ? if so, show us the pom.xml or build.gradle. check the classpath to see if the jars actually are available

Comment: I'm not using maven (nor do I know what it does). Is it essential to run spring applications?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, right click on project and there is an option to add Maven nature, select it. It will generate a POM.xml, in that you can add the dependencies of all the libraries you are going to require.

Comment: @WeareBorg I don't see that option. I suppose it's because I didn't create a maven project. I'm new at this so I don't know if maven is required to build applications. Is it?

Comment: Here is the image dictating that the option is available. http://bit.do/disablemaven . Secondly, for Spring apps, having Maven is good, or any other dependency management tool like Gradle(Glacier slow), Ant(not recommended, too old). Look for it, and read docs.

Comment: Thanks @WeareBorg but for the moment I would prefer not using Maven if it's not essential. Just to play around for a little bit, learning the basics.

Comment: Well, for Spring project, technically it's not essential, but personally I would say it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103005/discussion-between-sedulam-and-we-are-borg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using maven you need to add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I'm not using maven (nor do I know what it does). Is it essential to run spring applications?

Comment: It is most definitely recommended to use either gradle or maven. But I guess if you really don't want to use it. you can download the jar from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE and then add it to you project

Answer (score 0):

I changed Dalston.SR4 to Edgware.SR3 in pom properties. It works like charm.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```