# IntelliJ: Cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm trying to start my first project with Spring. I use IntelliJ idea and I'm kind of new to it too. But anyways, I followed the step written on the Jetbrains website and I don't know what I have done wrong, but I got a lot of errors on the first to files that are created by default.

BloomBookingApplcation.java

```
package com.bloombooking;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BloomBookingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BloomBookingApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Error:(3, 12) Cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'
Error:(4, 12) Cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'
Error:(6, 2) Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringBootApplication'
Warning:(7, 1) Access can be packageLocal
Error:(9, 26) Cannot resolve symbol 'String'
Error:(10, 3) Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringApplication'
```

Maybe I'm stupid but I don't know which step I've missed...

How can I fix this?

I have found the way to add spring with the quickfix button.

But now I have got new errors I don't understand why... I should maybe download it directly and put the libraries one by one maybe?

```
Error:(3, 28) Cannot resolve symbol 'boot'
Error:(4, 28) Cannot resolve symbol 'boot'
Error:(6, 2) Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringBootApplication'
Warning:(7, 1) Access can be packageLocal
Error:(9, 26) Cannot resolve symbol 'String'
Error:(10, 3) Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringApplication'
```

Or maybe it's my IntelliJ idea which isn't configured right since I don't have any completion anywhere and I can't create packages...

Comment: You didn't add the Spring .jar files to the classpath?

Comment: Arf ! I didn't knew it wouldn't be done automatically .. I've searched and found how to do it thx to you :)

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol 'String'" - looks like your Java installation is broken or you have not configured the JDK in Intellij

Comment: Mmmhh it is kind of strange cause when i go into project structure the jdk 1.8 appear ..

Comment: My JDK Wasn't configured as it  should have been i've found how to do it properly here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618794/intellj-idea-cannot-resolve-symbol-and-cannot-resolve-method

Comment: After that i've decided to delete all and redo it again and it work like magic :)

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Your are missing some dependencies. Try this ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293116/import-org-springframework-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 64):

[image]

Click on refresh button .Maven may not be able to sync properly

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I had created the project based on a new Maven project, and while I could use `mvn` on the CLI, Intellij was showing me the errors that Atoine had.

Comment: Did this,. Nothing changed

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem, and this is how it worked for me:

On the source root directory -> right click -> Add Framework Support.

A window will open with different categories, such as Java EE, JBoss etc.
Go to 'Spring' category. Then, download the pack of libraries that you need (I used 'Spring MVC').

Comment: there is no spring MVC. Only Groovy

Comment: Could not find "spring" in the list of framework support

Comment: You will find "Spring" only in the Intellij Ultimate Edition. You can go with "Application" in the configuration.

Answer (score 8):

In my case triggering an ***Invalidate Caches/Restart*** helped IntelliJ now find those dependencies.

[image: The Invalidate Caches/Restart option]

Following what Mr. BlueSky told in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48741568/10232790), I could get the dependencies downloaded.
Actually, the [answer by Vinayak Shedgeri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51797001/10232790) should have helped too. For those whom it didn't, you could try the **invalidate cache/restart**.

**P. S.:** And going by what could have caused this behavior, you could very well try something as simple as relaunching IntelliJ first. Just a guess.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on the project and select **Open In → Terminal**

[image: Context Menu]

In the terminal, type → `mvn -U idea:idea`

[image: terminal]

It will resolve all the classpath issues for the particular project

Comment: Thank you, cloned my project from github and tried adding /src as source but it didn't work until I ran this cmd.

Comment: Fixed my issues as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Project root directory -> right click -> Add Framework Support --> Maven or Gradle --> Click Ok

Comment: I couldnt find it

Answer (score 6):

Please check if you have configured Maven Settings.

IntelliJ (File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Maven )

Maven home path : C:/Program Files/apache-maven-3.6.0

It resolved my error.

Answer (score 5):

Add dependency for springframework in `pom.xml` and run below command from directory where `pom.xml` exist.

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Above command will forcefully download the dependencies.

if you are behind proxy then try below command

```
mvn clean install -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=www-proxy.us.com -DproxyPort=80
```

Comment: Non-resolvable parent POM for the SNAPSHOT

Comment: I have faced the same issue as the OP. I had started the project from the scratch using IntelliJ IDE and spring initializer. The  maven wasn't installed separately even though it was available as part of the project. I installed maven separately from this link https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi. Run the above command and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me was to close Intellij, erase the idea folder and open it again, Intellij seems to check everything again and then my dependency hasn't any issues

Comment: I tried everything and only suggestion that worked for me was this.

Comment: Only solution that worked. I should point out that you should delete .idea folder in the root of your project since the answer doesn't specify which folder to delete exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was behind Office proxy and that why MAVEN was unable to download the required dependencies on its own !

After switching the network and executing below command : `mvn clean install -U`, it worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Check if

> /Users/<userName>/.m2/

location has settings.xml and toolchains.xml.
I think toolchains might not be necessary but settings.xml is required.
Instructions for creating settings.xml can be found here - https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

My issue was resolved after adding settigs.xml and toolchains.xml to above mentioned location and restarting the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Maven did not added dependencies on intellij so for this problem I restarted intellij IDE and when this time IDE stared it added dependencies successfully.

Answer (score 0):

import parent folder(Backend) instead of child folder(exam).

child folder(exam)

[image: exam folder]

parent folder(Backend)

[image: Backend folder]

Answer (score 0):

I had a few spring-boot modules which were in perfect running state, but suddenly my PC went off and that created issues like: cannot resolve symbol 'springframework' and etc

[Maven -> Reload all maven projects] : this fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your IDE (Intellij) and it should ask you to start loading of the maven project.
It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First open maven window from right panel
[image]

then click maven settings

[image]

next change maven home path
[image]

after that reload maven project with this
[image]

if this maven home path is not working you can change it to another home path for checking